# Pretty something or Nice something

Tags: phrase-usage

Can we use `Pretty`instead of `Nice` when we want to give a compliment? Reason I am asking is I want to sound less cliche. For example, can I say:

> That's a pretty nickname!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use *pretty* for a girl’s nickname, but not a boy’s nickname. The word *pretty* is typically used for (or associated with) feminine things (“That’s a pretty dress!”) or scenes in nature (“What a pretty sunset!”). You don’t hear “pretty” used for masculine things very often, and, when you do, it might be laced with a bit of sarcasm. (This isn't universally true, but it’s often the case. [Here’s a supporting ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+pretty+face%2Cher+pretty+face&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).)